# Relationship between IO#Socket and IO#Manager

Tags: websocket, socket.io

When I read socket.io [client API](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/),notice the api expose Manger and Socket interface which look quite similar in terms of event and method

Also,I can conclude from the doc that we can get manager instance from a socket instance by `socket.io` and manager instance contains and socket instance by `manager.engine` .That is all I know

Given their APIs are almost the same ,for example,I can not tell any difference between `manager.disconnet()` and `socket.disconnect()`.I think the root reason is I can not get the relationship between then

Comment: This is explained here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#manager